# InetGet not working as expected

Tags: download, autoit

I wrote a simple patcher application which downloads a file into configured directory.

When I download some files from the URL via patcher, application which the dll file belongs to doesn't run (when I click 'open' nothing happens). Here is my code cut:

```
Local $fileDownload = InetGet("http://myurl.com/library.dll" , "library.dll" , 1 , 1)
```

Everything is fine, and if I remove the `library.dll` AutoIt is downloading it, but then the main application doesn't run.

If I download and replace the file manually (via web browser) everything is fine. So looks like `InetGet()` corrupts the file. But I don't know how and why.

Comment: Is it an issue of it being run in the background (the last arg in the `InetGet` function call)? Are you closing the handle (`InetClose()`) before the download is complete?

Comment: @DevNull I dont know if its caused by being running in the background, I can check that. I'm closing the handle after downloading.

Comment: Try stripping off that last arg and see if that helps. (The default is to wait until the download is complete.) You could also change the "1" to a "9" to force binary, but I think that only works for FTP. The command line would be `InetGet("http://myurl.com/library.dll" , "library.dll" , 9)`

Comment: @DevNull Here is the code, if you wish look on it: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ccMNBZvr

Comment: Running Tidy over your code probably helps... it's very miss-indented. With a correct identation you'd probably find some errors?? And why do you juse delete your downloaded file again in line 162?
Anyway, your code won't run here and I don't understand your messages. So sorry I can't give you any further help. But honestly: tidying up your code might help tracking down errors... ;-)

Comment: @JohannesThomasMeyer There are no errors... Just bugs , I hope. About the 162 line, it does delete the file before downloading... as I said if I paste the file manually, it works, but I noticed something important: if a file named `library.dll` exist in a directory, the app doesn't run BUT if I remove the file manually, and then patch (so it'll download the file via patcher) it works. So I don't understand that... So thats why I tried to delete the file before downloading new one, but unfotunately it doesn't help.

Comment: But then you have to run the `FileDelete(...)` right **before** you use the `InetGet(...)`? Means swap lines 162 and 161?

And yeah, your script might not contain syntax errors, but I meant the "bugs". Do you know [Tidy](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/scite/docs/tidy_doc.htm)?

Comment: @JohannesThomasMeyer You're right, but I swaped line 162 with the 161 and no results, works as before, so it's strange. About the Tidy, ofc. I was trying to run it, but it probably doesn't work on Windows7 with x64 architecture, because I get an error saying: `System could not locate the path specified.`

Comment: Open library.dll with notepad after the download with InetGet.

Answer (score 2):

inet_get should work! anyway here is another aproach download the file directly with winapi method using my function than save it to a file

```
Func get_url($url)

    $RequestURL = $url;
    Global $oHTTP = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1") ;
    $oHTTP.Open("GET", $RequestURL, False)
    $oHTTP.Send()
     if  $oHTTP.status == 200 Then
           Return $oHTTP.ResponseText
     Else
            Return  "ooops... status: " & $oHTTP.status  
     EndIf

 EndFunc
```